# Eigen - Map a const array to a dynamic vector

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

I need to define a function that takes a `const` C array and maps it into an `Eigen` map. The following code gives me an error:

```
double data[10] = {0.0};
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> MapVec;

MapVec fun(const double* data) {
  MapVec vec(data, n);
  return vec;
}
```

If I remove `const` from the function definition the code works fine. But is it possible to retain the `const` without any errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `Map`'s parameter is a non-`const` type (e.`Eigen::VectorXd`) then it assumes that it can modify the raw buffer (in your case `*data`). As the function expects a `const` qualified buffer, you have to tell the map that it's `const`. Define your `typedef` as

```
typedef Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd> MapVec;
```

and it should work.

Comment: does it mean that the MapVec is a const and cannot be changed later?

Comment: @X.Arthur The original data cannot be changed as it's `const`, as in OP. The address of the data to which the Map points cannot be changed either, except with placement new, although that has nothing to do with OP.